# Purging nginx didnt delete the configuration files

Tags: 12.04, nginx, purge

I just ran

```
sudo apt-get purge nginx
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

but the folder `/etc/nginx/`still exists, with all its content intact.

I guess I could `rm` the folder but that is not the point of my question. I would like to know why it wasn't deleted automatically, as `purge` should do. **Did I miss a step?**

I am running Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even better:
`sudo apt-get purge nginx*`

Comment: Great point! Now that is more complete :) But there is a danger in this command... imagine what would happen if by accident you put a space between `nginx` and `*`. I always take care of using wildcards in `apt-get`

Comment: @Dbugger Hadn't thought of that. Though am **always** careful when using wildcards especially the `*`. Confirm your command before pressing enter.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind. I got it.

```
sudo apt-get purge nginx-common
```